# Set element id while using paper.add() in raphael.js

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am using the following paper.add, is there a way to set an id when declaring these elements?

```
paper.add([{
    "type": "circle",
    "fill": "#858AB5",
    "stroke": "none",
    "cx": 182.511,
    "cy": 178.146,
    "r": 162
}, {
    "type": "rect",
    "fill": "none",
    "stroke": "none",
    "x": 49.095,
    "y": 145.852,
    "width": 261.809,
    "height": 79.397
}, {
    "type": "text",
    "fill": "#FFFFFF",
    "stroke": "none",
    "transform": "t79.9719,174.3274",
    "font-family": "Impact",
    "font-size": 36,
    "text-anchor": "start",
    "text": "Darma & Greg"
} {
    "type": "text",
    "fill": "#FFFFFF",
    "stroke": "none",
    "transform": "t93.4012,211.6449",
    "font-family": "Impact",
    "font-size": 33,
    "text-anchor": "start",
    "text": "July 12th 2014"
}, {
    "type": "path",
    "fill": "#FFFFFF",
    "stroke": "none",
    "path": "M190.441,32.469c0,4.932-3.998,8.93-8.93,8.93c-4.932,0-8.93-3.998-8.93-8.93s3.998-8.93,8.93-8.93\r\n\t\t\tC186.443,23.538,190.441,27.537,190.441,32.469z"
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a method to set the id while using paper.add();  So i resorted to this little snippet of code.

```
paper.forEach(function (el) {

    if (el.type =='text'){
        elements.push(el)

   elements[counted].node.onclick = selected;
 elements[counted].node.id = counted;

 ft = paper.freeTransform(elements[counted], {  drag: ['center', 'self'],
        rotate: ['axisY'],
        scale: ['bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
        keepRatio: ['bboxCorners'],
        snap: {
            rotate: 5
        },
        draw: 'bbox'
     }, function(ft, events) {
        console.log(ft.attrs);
    });


counted ++; 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late to answer but you can use **Element.data(key, [value])** to set any data you want .

Have a look here http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data